# How to get with JAVA a specific value for one substring from string?

Tags: java, substring

I have ONE string field which is in format:

```
"TransactionID=30000001197169 ExecutionStatus=6
        additionalCurrency=KMK
    pin= 0000"
```

So they are not separated with some ; оr ,  they are not seperated even with one blank space.

I want to get value for Execution Status and put it in some field?
How to achieve this?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example they are indeed seperated by blanks, but the following should be working without blanks, too. Assuming your String is stored in `String arguments`

```
String executionStatus;
String[] anArray = arguments.split("=");
for (int i; i < anArray.length; i++)
    if (anArray[i].contains("ExecutionStatus")){
        executionStatus = anArray[++i].replace("additionalCurrency","");
        executionStatus = executionStatus.trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: my result is  "6   additionalCurrency"   so I must cut additionalCurrency from result

Comment: yes thanks. one small question - what if additionalCurrency is not always the second parameter in string? Thanks for help

Comment: first, it doesn't matter, which place executionStatus is. You should trim the string correctly, when the order can change. either you replace all occurences of parameters like `"additionalCurrency"` with `""`, or you trim the string with other options (possibily a blank yet).

Answer (score 3):

This works. But I am not sure this is the most optimal.It just solves your problem.

```
    String s = "TransactionID=30000001197169ExecutionStatus=6additionalCurrency=KMKpin=0000";
    if(s!=null && s.contains("ExecutionStatus="))
    {
        String s1[] = s.split("ExecutionStatus=");
        if(s1!=null &&  s1.length>1)
        {
            String line = s1[1];
            String pattern = "[0-9]+";

              // Create a Pattern object
              Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

              // Now create matcher object.
              Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
              if (m.find( )) {
                 System.out.println("Match");
                 System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );

              } else {
                 System.out.println("NO MATCH");
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The above code is dynamic. It does not matter what comes after 6 or what comes before ExecutionStatus= . It will only search for the value of ExecutionStatus as you desired

Comment: As you can see the code has used regular expression. it searches [0-9+] means any length of numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

Check if it `contains()` `ExecutionStatus=`

If yes then split the string with `ExecutionStatus=`

Now take the Second string from `array` find the first occurance of non digit char and use `substring()`

Comment: can you write me the shortest cod for this? sorry for disturbing

Comment: I have given enough(dirty) information, Please check api doc and try to write by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all that white space is present in your string, this works.

```
String str = "\"TransactionID=30000001197169 ExecutionStatus=6\n" +
        "        additionalCurrency=\"KMK\"\n" +
        "    pin= \"0000\"\"";
int start = str.indexOf("ExecutionStatus=") + "ExecutionStatus=".length();
int status = 0;

if (start >= 0) {
    String strStatus = str.substring(start, str.indexOf("additionalCurrency=") - 1);
    try {
        status = Integer.parseInt(strStatus.trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of attracting "... and now you have two problems!" comments, this is probably easiest done with regexes (str is the String defined above):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ExecutionStatus\\s*=\\s*(\\d+)"); // Whitespace matching around equals for safety, capturing group around the digits of the status)
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
String status = m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
```